# How to bypass registry reflection (Wow6432Node)?

Tags: 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, registry

I want to extract certain information from the registry but since my script is running inside a 32-bit engine, it will extract information only from the Wow6432Node for certain keys.  Is there a way to bypass registry reflection and read from both

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft

and

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft

?

I just want to read the values from the keys, not update it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read and write specifically to the 32 or 64 bit views of the registry by passing [different flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to the `RegOpenKeyEx/RegCreateKeyEx` functions: `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` and `KEY_WOW64_32KEY`