# WOW6432Node registry problem

Tags: visual-c++

I made  my application as install setup by install shield 5.0 on 32bit machine but before that i migrated my application into 64bit. after installed my application on 64bit machine, my application registry values are gone into under wow6432 node as HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node(myapplication) but my application trying to read those values from HKLM\SOFTWARE(myapplication). could you please where is the wrong. what shall i do this case.

thanks,
KAM

Answer (score 0):

Your install is 32-bit and it automatically writes to Wow6432Node on 64-bit system. You need to disable registry reflection or to directly write to 64-bit registry key (I don't know how to do that on install shield, but you should find it in the manual, search for Registry Reflection).

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110543/how-to-bypass-registry-reflection-wow6432node/4110718#4110718) on how to explicitly read the 32 or 64-bit 'views' of the registry.  You have a few options depending on your situation - you can make the 32-bit version read the 64-bit view (so it'll use HKLM/Software.  This means that you won't need to change the installer) or you could force the 64-bit version read the 32-bit view (this may be better if you need different options in the 32 and 64-bit versions)